# openSCAD WARNING: PolySet has degenerate polygons

Tags: openscad

In openSCAD I am writing a `polyhedron`. The preview shows the polyhedron, but if I try to render it, the entire polyhedron is not shown. I get the warning message:

```
WARNING: PolySet has degenerate polygons
```

The polyhedron has no holes. I checked that.

Comment: What does the code look like? can you paste some in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Check the faces of the polyhedron for their orientation. If some of them are facing inwards, some outwards, that can be the problem.

Check the [openSCAD manual for the polyhedron](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids#polyhedron) to learn how to identify the orientation of the faces. Basically you must be able to count the points of the faces in clockwise order if you are looking at the face from the outside. When the thrown together view (F12) is used you can make counter clockwise faces visible by pressing F5. The pink ones are CCW. You can change their orientation by permuting two of the points of the triangle. For example change [0,4,5]) to [4,0,5].

Other problems might throw the same warning. For example when two faces match too exactly like diskussed in [this thread on the opnenscad forum](http://forum.openscad.org/2015-01-23-Throws-a-WARNING-PolySet-has-degenerate-polygons-warning-td11262.html).